# Sequential pattern with numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I would like to automatically fill (3x3x3) numpy array of zeros with the pattern the looks like this this, it starts with the coordinate `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` then sequentially and in the order shown starts to increase the `z` by the amount of `3.5` and `y` by the amount `6.5` and `x` by the amount `6.5` in a sequential manner so that the result will be nodes of a lattice in a 3d-space

```
0.0 6.5 1.0
0.0 6.5 4.5
0.0 6.5 8.0
0.0 13.5 1.0
0.0 13.5 4.5
0.0 13.5 8.0
0.0 21.0 1.0
0.0 21.0 4.5
0.0 21.0 8.0
6.5 6.5 1.0
6.5 6.5 4.5
6.5 6.5 8.0
6.5 13.5 1.0
6.5 13.5 4.5
6.5 13.5 8.0
13.5 21.0 1.0
13.5 21.0 4.5
13.5 21.0 8.0
21.0 6.5 1.0
21.0 6.5 4.5
21.0 6.5 8.0
21.0 13.5 1.0
21.0 13.5 4.5
21.0 13.5 8.0
21.0 21.0 1.0
21.0 21.0 4.5
21.0 21.0 8.0
```

Comment: It is not clear to me how your desired numpy array is associated with the dictionary. Since it is just a 3x3x3, maybe you can show it directly so it would be explicit what you are looking for.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post text that is appropriately formatted as a code block.

Comment: Make a simpler example. Show your output. Show the code you tried.

Comment: Always remember: we can't read your mind. Reduce everything to fundamentals you think we can agree on, like definitions of "array", "python", "numpy", etc

Comment: Your text is still not consistent with the output and you don't show any code that you attempted.

Comment: Specifically, `z` starts with 1 for some reason, not 0 as you claim

Comment: @MadPhysicist `z` has a constant factor for its increase, the main trouble for me is that `x` and `y` increase not by a static step of increment

Comment: 13.5-6.5 != 21-13.5

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your specific arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.indices` to generate coordinate arrays. If your grid is evenly spaced, you can scale and offset it to whatever shape you want:

```
np.indices((4, 3, 3)).reshape(3, -1).T * [6.5, 7.5, 3.5] + [0, 6, 1]
```

If you want the grid as a 3D grid instead of a 27x3 array, just remove the bits with `.reshape(3, -1).T` and change the scale and offsets appropriately.

If your grid is irregular or non-linear in some way, you can provide the arrays that make it up and combine them individually. `np.meshgrid` is the tool for this job:

```
x = np.array([0.0, 6.5, 13.5, 21.0])
y = np.array([6.5, 13.5, 21.0])
z = np.linspace(1.0, 8.0, 3)

np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij'), -1).reshape(-1, 3)
```

Again, if you want the 3D grid, remove the bit about `.reshape(-1, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want.  Use itertools.product to create the Cartesian product of all of your values.

```
>>> z = list(itertools.product((0.0,6.5,13.5,21.0),(6.5,13.5,21.0),(1,4.5,9.0)))
>>> z = np.array(z)
>>> z
array([[ 0. ,  6.5,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  6.5,  4.5],
       [ 0. ,  6.5,  9. ],
       [ 0. , 13.5,  1. ],
       [ 0. , 13.5,  4.5],
       [ 0. , 13.5,  9. ],
       [ 0. , 21. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. , 21. ,  4.5],
       [ 0. , 21. ,  9. ],
       [ 6.5,  6.5,  1. ],
       [ 6.5,  6.5,  4.5],
       [ 6.5,  6.5,  9. ],
       [ 6.5, 13.5,  1. ],
       [ 6.5, 13.5,  4.5],
       [ 6.5, 13.5,  9. ],
       [ 6.5, 21. ,  1. ],
       [ 6.5, 21. ,  4.5],
       [ 6.5, 21. ,  9. ],
       [13.5,  6.5,  1. ],
       [13.5,  6.5,  4.5],
       [13.5,  6.5,  9. ],
       [13.5, 13.5,  1. ],
       [13.5, 13.5,  4.5],
       [13.5, 13.5,  9. ],
       [13.5, 21. ,  1. ],
       [13.5, 21. ,  4.5],
       [13.5, 21. ,  9. ],
       [21. ,  6.5,  1. ],
       [21. ,  6.5,  4.5],
       [21. ,  6.5,  9. ],
       [21. , 13.5,  1. ],
       [21. , 13.5,  4.5],
       [21. , 13.5,  9. ],
       [21. , 21. ,  1. ],
       [21. , 21. ,  4.5],
       [21. , 21. ,  9. ]])
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your effort, but It seems that misarticulated one thing that for `x` and `y` it starts with `0.0` then we increase `6.5` then we increase `7` then finally we increase `7.5` so the factor is not constant as we can see, that is my problem.

Comment: So, we can't use the (0,1,2) trick.  That just means you need to specify the values to `itertools.product`, as above.

Comment: `np.meshgrid` is the numpythonic version of `itertools.product`